# Using show() with twill spams the console with HTML

Tags: python, twill

I've been using the fuction `twill.commands.show()` to get the raw HTML from a page. I run this about every 5 seconds. Every time the function is ran, It spams the console with the mentioned webpages raw HTML. I need to use the console for debugging, and since the console is filled with HTML constantly, Doing so is impossible. Since `show()` is programmed to print the HTML and return it as a string, I would have to edit twill, which is *way* beyond my skillset, and makes the program incompatible on other devices. Although saving and reading the file over and over might work, it seems impractical to do every 5 seconds.

Code:

```
go('http://google.com/')
html=show()
```

Again, twill has a `save_html`, which could be used to save to a file, but I'm doing this every 5 seconds and it could slow the program/computer, especially if it's being run on an older OS.

Thanks!

Comment: would you be so kind as to include some code that you've tried, so we have a case we can try and reproduce?

Comment: @sircapsalot just did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twill writes to `stdout` by default.

You can use `twill.set_output(fp)` for redirecting its standard output. There're several possible implementations for doing this:

Write to a `StringIO`:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
sio = StringIO()
twill.set_output(sio)
html = show() # html+'\n' == sio.getvalue()
```

or to `/dev/null`:

```
import os
null = open(os.devnull, 'w')
twill.set_output(null)
html = show() # writing to /dev/null or nul
null.close()
```

or to nothing at all:

```
class DevNull(object):
    def write(self, str):
        pass
twill.set_output(DevNull())
html = show()
```

or to any other writable file-like python object of your liking.

Comment: Thanks! (I used the last one)

Answer (score 1):

Capture output in a string and replace all tags with empty string using regex, so that you can get text.

```
import re
from StringIO import StringIO

sio = StringIO()
twill.set_output(sio)
show()
print(re.sub(r'<.*?>','',sio.getvalue(),flags=re.DOTALL))
```

Comment: Why is replacing tags necessary?

Comment: You said 'to get the text', I thought you wanted only text in the html.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant raw HTML